# Playing with Bazel C++ tutorials; build does not create/use shared libraries?

Tags: c++, build, bazel

Looking at Bazel today for the first time.

On building the [cpp tutorial](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/tutorial/cpp.html), I can see how it builds simple executables and archive libraries, but it doesn't look like the examples create or use shared libraries.

Does anyone know of simple example BUILD files to demonstrate this process? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A shared library is a `cc_binary`:

```
cc_binary(
    name = "libfoo.so",
    srcs = ["foo.cc"],
    linkshared = 1,     ## important
)
```

(In non-trivial situations, you should probably also add `linkstatic = 1` to get a self-contained DSO that does not itself have load-time dependencies on its source dependencies.)

Comment: Aren't prefix and suffix (`lib` and `.so`) supposed to be added automatically?

Comment: @VTT: No, I don't think so.

Comment: Thanks.  What's the rationale for categorizing a shared library as a `cc_binary`, but an archive library as a `cc_library`?

Comment: That leads to the second half of my question: when I try to link an executable with this, I get an analysis phase error:  

`ERROR: /home/dcf/workdir/bazel/examples/cpp-tutorial/stage3/main/BUILD:10:12: in deps attribute of cc_binary rule //main:hello-world: cc_binary rule '//lib:libhello.so' is misplaced here (expected cc_library, objc_library, cc_proto_library or cc_import)`  

How do I link against an object of type `cc_binary`?

Comment: You would never manually "build dynamic libraries" in bazel. Just use `cc_library`s and `deps`. You'd only ever build a DSO (as in my answer) in order to use it with, say, `dlopen`. It looks like you're fundamentally thinking about your build in the wrong way. Whether a `cc_library` emits any DSOs or just static archives is just a detail of the build process (e.g. controlled with `--dynamic_mode`.)

Comment: +1 to what Kerrek SB said. Think of the cc_library as a group of objects, not as a .a or .so. Depending on the toolchain and configuration used cc_library might only build object files, sometimes also .a, sometimes also .so, and Bazel will pick one of these 3 outputs at various times. And most importantly, you should not use .a and .so created by cc_library anywhere, it's an implementation detail. This is also relevant for the future: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1d4SPgVX-OTCiEK_l24DNWiFlT14XS5ZxD7XhttFbvrI/edit?ts=5977ad15#heading=h.jwrigiapdkr2

Comment: I've finally had a chance to look at this again, and what Kerrek and mhlopko is starting to make sense. I'm looking at Bazel as a possible replacement for an existing product build process (Ant- and Make-based), and realizing that it will be a big conceptual switch.

Comment: @KerrekSB One may want to test the shared library with their test application, or write an application as an example of the shared library usage. I agree with the rest cases though.

Comment: @DmitryT. If the library is your own, then the way you'd arrange that is to have a `cc_library` with the source code, and a separate `cc_binary` with no sources and only the library as a dependency and producing a DSO. Your test application would then just depend on the library directly. If the library is foreign, then you can make the DSO part of the srcs of your test application.

Comment: @KerrekSB I agree with your point if we talk about unit tests, but having some integration tests is usually a good idea too.

Comment: @KerrekSB I was initially using the approach you described and turns out `bazel` does NOT link the shared library targets specified in `deps`, it only triggers the build for those.

Comment: @logicor: Sorry, I don't have full context anymore, but whether a dep can be linked statically depends on whether it consists of source code, object code, or a prelinked DSO. The latter of course cannot be "relinked"; the former two should work.

Comment: @KerrekSB, the last one was actually the center of discussion here.  In a project where I have an DSO as final product, as well as test suites simulates user's behavior by linking against that DSO, it is rather difficult the get latter build properly in `bazel`.

Comment: @logicor: Maybe that sounds more like you want the DSO to be in the `srcs` of the test, not in its deps? The former lets you truly link against the DSO, at the expense of having the DSO renamed to some uniquely mangled place and an rpath added your test binary.

Answer (score 5):

In order to perform dynamic linking, you must first import the shared library. You should specify the library headers, the library binary and the interface library (required for Windows only, not present in this example):

```
# Build the shared library
cc_binary(
    name = "libfoo.so",
    srcs = ["foo.cc"],
    linkshared = 1,     ## important
)

# Import the shared library
cc_import(
    name = "imported_libfoo",
    hdrs = ["foo.h"],
    shared_library = "libfoo.so",
)

# Link to the shared library
cc_binary(
    name = "bar",
    deps = [":imported_libfoo"],
)
```

Comment: This solution provides what I am looking for.  However there is one carveat: if you `bazel build imported_libfoo` it is a nop. Only when you `bazel build bar` it would correctly trigger the build for `libfoo.so`.  Tried with bazel version 2.1.1 and 3.1.0.

Comment: This is a really useful answer for me to understand how to write tf_kernel_library in simpler components. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Based on the above method, I add a little exception.

Take an example above, if you so library also deps on another `cc_library`, do add `alwayslink = True` to the `cc_library`, otherwise the shared library will not have a symlink.

```
cc_library(
    name = "hello-greet-lib",
    srcs = ["hello-greet.cc"],
    hdrs = ["hello-greet.h"],
    alwayslink = True,   # important
)

cc_binary(
    name = "libhello-greet.so",  # the shared library
    linkshared = True,
    deps = [":hello-greet-lib"],
)

cc_import(
    name = "hello-greet",
    shared_library = "libhello-greet.so",
    hdrs = ["hello-greet.h"],
)

cc_binary(
    name = "hello-world",
    srcs = ["hello-world.cc"],
    deps = [
        ":hello-greet",
        "//lib:hello-time",
    ],
)
```

this is common when you need to aggregate some libraries, so do remember add `alwayslink = True` if you want to generate the dynamic library in the above way